# Bootstrap: make a CSS rule apply only on desktop version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a desktop and a mobile version of an app.

I want the desktop version to have a small image in the top-left corner, almost like a watermark, that won't affect the positioning of any other elements, so I used a background-image on the body

```
body
{
    background-image: url("../image/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However, I do not want this to display on the mobile version.

How can I stop this CSS rule affecting the mobile version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a class on the body tag:

```
body.desktop
{
    background-image: url("../image/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<body class="desktop">
...
</body>
```

You could also use [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to remove the image for small screen sizes. No body class would be needed in this case:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {background-image: none;}
}
```

Comment: I don't even know why you'd recommend a class here, how do you expect this class to get applied?  When using media queries, its better to apply the bg when `(min-width: X)` rather than apply it globally and remove it after the fact.  Less CSS that way.  There's rarely a good reason to use `min-device-width` over `min-width` (same goes for their `max-*` counterparts).

Comment: I don't understand your issue with the body class. As for the media query, it's a general example open to modification. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks guys, this did the trick.

`@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
        body{ 
            background-image: url("../image/logo.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    }`

Comment: The issue with the body class was that I'd have to create two entirely separate `<body>`s, thus defeating the purpose of bootstrap.

Comment: Your question implied that you had two different sites. Even if you don't, your app can apply classes based on any number of parameters.